Prereqs for learning Variational Quantum Eigensolver (VQE)
I am trying to learn Variational Quantum Eigensolver algorithm(s) for a class.
However, I am struggling because I don't understand any of the problems we are trying to solve.
I want to know what I need to know to successfully learn VQE and implement a sample algorithm in Qiskit.
I am a sophomore studying computer science. I've taken linear algebra, discrete math, all the calculus', mechanics and E&M, machine learning, and a few intro probability classes.
Are there any good resources to learn the basic supplemental knowledge to be able to understand why we need VQE and how to solve a problem using VQE.
Any comments are much appreciated. Thank you!

Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32720/10454 https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32733/10454

The material from IBM Quantum Learning provides an excellent background for studying VQE. A good sequence to follow would be:

Basics of quantum information
Fundamentals of quantum algorithms
Variational algorithm design

VQE (among other quantum variational algorithms) is discussed in the variational algorithm design course.
